# Entity Framework 6.1 Code First

Tags: entity-framework-6, code-first

I am trying to start with Entity Framework 6.1 Code First and want to connect to an existing database. Problem is that I am not able to choose neither Empty Code First model nor Code First from database, when I try to add a new ADO.NET Entity Data Model as it is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620). Do I need some other NuGetPackages?

The example for a new database is working.

Any hints?

Kind regards
Patrick

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907.aspx ... Would be a great start.